# limesurvey is not working in some of safafri browsers

Tags: limesurvey

In my Local systems. We installed limesurvey opensources. But it is not validateing in the forms in some of safari browsers.
But version of safari browser 5.1.7. But same browser version some systems it is working and some systems it is not working

Comment: seems unlikely, what version of LS are you running?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information or, in fact, actually a question.

Comment: I am using version of limesurvery 2.00